# How to check if there exist an input with specific name attr using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I need a function to add new input element dynamically using jQuery.

It is something like this

```
function addInput(inputName) {
  $('<input>', {
    type: "hidden",
    name: "inputName"
  }).appendTo('#foo');
}

addInput('test');
```

and it works, It adds a new `<input type="hidden" name="test">` to `#foo`

Problem appears when I want to make this function add input only if input with specified name does not exists in `DOM`.

Here is my updated function

```
function addInput(inputName) {
  if (! $(input).attr('name','inputName') {
    $('<input>', {
      type: "hidden",
      name: "inputName"
    }).appendTo('#foo')
  }
}

addInput('test');
```

But insteed checking for `input` elements with the name `test` it sets name of all `input` elements to `test`.
Is there any method to only test input name?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Check `length` with [equal-selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/) like,

```
function addInput(inputName) {
  if (! $('input[name="'+inputName+'"]').length) {
    $('<input>', {
      type: "hidden",
      name: inputName
    }).appendTo('#foo')
  }
}
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/2pwYX/)

Answer (score 2):

```
function addInput(inputName) {
    if ($('input[name="'+inputName+'"]').length > 0)
     {
      alert("Exists");
     }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

if you work with jQuery just use `.is()` function:

```
if(input.is('[name="your_name"]')){
   //do some things!
}
```

[see in codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/brLOyz)

Comment: var input= $('input');